# how to browse image in sd card using android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard

I have some images in my emulator sdcard and i want to select a particular image on it. refer my code below,

```
int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
Intent i = new                   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Actually push a png image in my emulator sd card , but use the above code my emulator shows no media found. guide me,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick image using external app help(like gallery)?

```
public void pick(View V) {
    Intent it = new Intent();
    it.setType("image/*");
    it.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(it, 101);
}
```

I used onActivityResult here to output it on imageView later
And you can convert it to URI, Bitmap or whatever you need

Comment: @sivanesan1 Have you made sure you had images in Gallery of your emulator? Or try using an actual phone to test

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);    

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

switch(requestCode) { 
case 1:
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I tried above code , it displays "No media found" in select picture screen.can i check image found or not in emulator sdcard manually.

Comment: @sivanesan1 , have u added the image on emulater gallery

Comment: what i did was i push an image using DDMS->file explorer option. if i see in settings->storage(in emulator) the total memory space reduced but exactly dont know where it is saved in emulator. but i transfer that image from sdcard to server it transfers successfully.